# Given an AP $(u_1, u_2,...,u_n)$ and an AP $(k_1, k_2,...k_m)$...

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given  $(u_1, u_2,\ldots,u_n)$ is an AP and $(k_1, k_2,\ldots, k_m)$  is an AP of natural numbers with $1 \leq k_1 \leq k_2 \leq \cdots \leq k_m \leq n$, prove that $(u_{k_{1}},u_{k_{2}},....u_{k_{n}})$ is also an AP.

I tried solving it this way:

$∃l .1 ≤ l ≤n$

Because $(u_1, u_2,\ldots,u_n)$ is an AP, we have

$$\begin{align}
  u_{k_{l-1}} &= u_1 + (k_{l-1} - 1)d \\
  u_{k_l} &= u_1 + \; \; \; (k_l - 1)d \\
  u_{k_{l+1}} &= u_1 +  (k_{l+1} - 1)d
\end{align}$$

Consider,

$$u_{k_l} - u_{k_{l-1}}
= u_1 + (k_l - 1)d - [ \, u_1 + (k_{l-1} - 1)\,]
= d(k_l - k_{l-1}) \tag{1}$$

also,

$$u_{k_{l+1}} - u_{k_l}
= u_1 + (k_{l+1} - 1) - [ \,u_1 + (k_l - 1)d\,]
= d(k_{l+1} - k_l ) \tag{2}$$

Equations 1 and 2 are equal since $(k_1, k_2,\ldots, k_m)$ is an AP as well and $d$ is common difference which is a constant.

Now since we have proved
$$u_{k_l} - u_{k_{l-1}} = u_{k_l} - u_{k_{l+1}}$$
it can be concluded that
$(u_{k_{1}},u_{k_{2}},....u_{k_{n}})$ is an AP.

Comment: Instead of "a <sub>1", write: dau1d where d=dollar symbol and u=underscore symbol

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is correct. It could be slightly shortened once you have obtained these equations:

$$\tag{1}\begin{cases}
  u_{k_{l-1}} &=& u_1 + (k_{l-1} - 1)d \\
  u_{k_l} &=& u_1 + \; \; \; (k_l - 1)d \\
  u_{k_{l+1}} &=& u_1 +  (k_{l+1} - 1)d
\end{cases}$$

Here is how.

Recall that the characteristic property of a AP is the fact that, in a sequence of 3 *consecutive* terms, the central term is the arithmetical mean of the two others.

But using $(1)$, one has:

$$\dfrac{u_{k_{l-1}}+u_{k_{l+1}}}{2}=u_{k_l} \ \ \iff \ \ \dfrac{(k_{l-1} - 1)+(k_{l+1} - 1)}{2}=(k_{l} - 1)$$

$$\ \ \iff \ \ \dfrac{k_{l-1}+k_{l+1}}{2}=k_{l} $$

But the latter is true by hypothesis, thus the former ($\dfrac{u_{k_{l-1}}+u_{k_{l+1}}}{2}=u_{k_l}$) is true, proving that $(u_{k_l})$ is an AP.